# Confused about hoverIntent - how do I add it to mouseover and mouseout?

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I would like to add the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to my jQuery code to make things a little smoother, but I just can't figure out how to do so.

My jQuery is already working as it should;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $(".mix-download-details").hide()
        $(".mix-download a").mouseover(function(){
            $(".mix-download-details").slideDown(200)
        });
        $(".mix-download a").mouseout(function(){
            $(".mix-download-details").slideUp(200)
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I would like the hoverintent to catch some of the unwanted behaviour. (multiple repeats etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You use hoverIntent like so:

```
$(".mix-download a").hoverIntent(function(){
    $(".mix-download-details").slideDown(200);
}, function(){
    $(".mix-download-details").slideUp(200);
});
```

<strike>Although hoverIntent should prevent animation stacking, I'd recommend adding [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before the animations as well:</strike>

```
$(".mix-download a").hoverIntent(function(){
    $(".mix-download-details").stop().slideDown(200);
}, function(){
    $(".mix-download-details").stop().slideUp(200);
});
```

Comment: When you use `.stop()` for animations, you nearly always need `.stop(true)` to remove the animation from the queue and you would need that in this case.

Comment: Thanks for that - so it's just not used with mouseover/mouseout?

Comment: The .stop() actually seems to add some strange side effects. If the user hovers and the animation starts, then the stop hovering before it is complete (ie: half way down) the next time they hover, it will only get as far as half way...

Comment: OK, ignore that part. No hoverIntent doesn't override `mouseover`/`mouseout`, which is probably a good thing.